# Chamadas Web Api 2

Tags: c#, android, api, asp.net-web-api, selenium-webdriver

Bem, tenho uma tarefa um pouco chata que é o tratamento de captchas, eu faço uma requisição get enviando como parâmetro um código que quero acessar, minha API abre a página com Webdriver, mapeia e pega a url da imagem do captcha. Eu levo esse captcha para o Android e ele renderiza a imagem.

Após renderizar essa imagem, eu escrevo os dados da imagem e dou um post em meu servidor. Aqui é que mora o problema, eu envio o código na primeira vez com GET e o servidor me cospe uma imagem randômica, como faço para associar essa imagem randômica ao meu POST?

A imagem tenta demonstrar com as interrogações o que quero entender se vai acontecer ou não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Complicado que a api não mantém estado, o que dá pra fazer, mas não sei se é a melhor opção, é com token OAuth, vc adiciona a chave do captcha como um claim, depois vc posta o resultado usando esse token no cabeçalho da requisição, e compara o valor informado com a chave armazenada no claim. Mas enfim, podem existir possibilidades melhores.

Comment: Esse captcha (Assim como qualquer captcha) tem um código que identifica ele, para o servidor do captcha saber se a resposta é a correta ou não, as vezes é um cookie, um campo que vai junto com a resposta, um token na URL, etc, você não pode reaproveitar isso para identificar qual captcha que é ?